# DAX Calculate Distinct Count only for values in both Table A and B per User

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am attempting to calculate the distinct count of site visits for a user (in TableA) but only for sites that the user currently has access to (in TableB). The way the data is structured a user may have a visited record in TableA for sites that no longer exist or that they no longer have access to for various reasons, and are therefore no record exists for that site in TableB for that user. I'm looking for a solution in Power Query, a measure or calculated column.

Table A:

| User | SiteID | Distinct Visits |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | A | 1 |
| Bob | B | 1 |
| Bob | D | 1 |
| Bob | E | 1 |
| Nancy | A | 1 |
| Nancy | B | 1 |

Table B:

| User | SiteID | Distinct Accessible Sites |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | A | 1 |
| Bob | C | 1 |
| Bob | D | 1 |
| Nancy | A | 1 |
| Nancy | B | 1 |
| Nancy | D | 1 |
| Nancy | E | 1 |

Table C:

| SiteID | Activity |
| --- | --- |
| A | Visited |
| A | Subscribed |
| A | Upgraded |
| B | Visited |
| B | Subscribed |
| C | Visited |
| C | Subscribed |
| C | Upgraded |
| D | Visited |
| E | Visited |
| E | Subscribed |
| E | Upgraded |

Table D:

| SiteID | Site Type |
| --- | --- |
| A | Personal |
| B | Personal |
| C | Business |
| D | Business |
| E | Business |

The count I currently have for Bob is 4 visits. In reality, he should only have 2 visits.

My current measures are:

The distinct # of times a Site has been visited by the User per Site filtered by Site Activity (TableC)

`Distinct Visits = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT('TableA'[SiteID]), 'TableC'[Activity] = "Visited")`

---Distinct # of Sites that the User has Access to filtered by Site Type (TableD)

`Distinct Accessible Sites = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT('TableB'[SiteID]), 'TableD'[Site Type] = "Personal" || 'TableD'[Site Type] = "Business")`

Is there a way to add an additional filter that only counts site visits for the sites Bob has access to? I attempted a calculated column flag, but it only excludes sites in TableA that are not in TableB overall, not per user:

`InAccessTable? = Contains('TableB', 'TableB'[SiteID], 'TableA'[SiteID])`

I also cannot figure out how to make a LOOKUPVALUE work for this. DAX is not my forte and using SQL is not an option currently. Thanks for any help!

Edit: Updated to include Table C and D and more user data

Comment: Where's your sample data fro Table C and Table D? Note that sample data with just one User for a calculation "by User" will prove nothing and only lead to endless discussions.

Comment: Can  you post your expected result given your sample data and show how you derive that result?

Comment: I would expect Bob to have 2 views in TableA (for sites A and D, because he has access to them in TableB) and Nancy to also have 2 views in TableA (for sites A and B, which she has access to in TableB).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would add a concatenated column (ideally in the Power Query Editor) combining User + SiteID to both Table A and B, then use that to create a relationship between the tables. Table A would be on the "many" side while Table B would be on the "one" side of the relationship. A relationship will avoid a lot of DAX code.

With that in place, you can apply simple filters on the visual, page or report e.g. Distinct Accessible Sites > 0. There's no need for complex DAX code.

[image: Model view of relationship]

[image: Visual-level filter]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the solution! I found another as well by creating a new merged table via an inner join in Power Query:

[image: Merge Query as New with Inner Join]

[image: Merged Table with Nonmatching Rows Removed]

[image: Results]